# GC.GetGeneration method gives unexpected results

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have sample code from Jeffrey Richter's book, which is shown below.

```
Object o = new Object();

Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 0. 
GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 1. 
GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 2 (expected) but it is 0
GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 2 (expected) but it is 1
```

Can anybody explain why 3rd and 4th calls to GetGeneration showed 0 and 1 generations instead of 2?

Comment: I tried your code in a console app and was able to see the expected results. Have you done anything else with the program/application to get these results?

Comment: Nope. Here is full code.  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object o = new Object();

            Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 0. 
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 1. 
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 2 (expected) 
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("Gen " + GC.GetGeneration(o)); // 2 (expected) 
        }
    }

Comment: @IgorLozovsky - Just update the question instead of trying to post code in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. The current .Net Framework of my console app is 3.5. When I changed it to 4 client profile I achieved expected results. But I have another question - what differences in garbage collection in .net 3.5 and 4.0 / 4.5?

Comment: For asking other questions, hit the `Ask Question` button or try to integrate it in your question, not answer.

Comment: Your second question needs... a question (this is an answer).